# Should I add a Network Interface between my Elastic IP and my instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-interface, elastic-ip

I created an elastic IP for my EC2 Instance and Route53 routes instance to my domain using that elastic IP.
However, someone mentioned the idea of connecting the Elastic IP to a network interface and then connecting the network interface to the EC2 Instance...

What's the point in adding the network interface in between and should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Elastic IP is **always** attached to a network interface.

However, when you attach address directly to an instance, AWS attaches it to instance's primary network interface, replacing any existing IP this interface had already attached to it. So the use case for attaching IP to an interface first, for example, includes the need to preserve the IP which is already associated with instance's primary NI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#eip-basics

Answer (score 0):

If you created multiple network interfaces, you could select to associate the EIP to a particular NI. You may have created multiple NI for load balancing, private communication a backup network between instances. You could configure connection to database servers as such.